# Migrating from lib/pq to jackc/pgx

Tags: go, pgx

After migrating project to "[github.com/jackc/pgx/pgxpool](https://godoc.org/github.com/jackc/pgx)" I have an error on every query:

`expected 0 arguments, got 1`

I noticed that error occurs at **Scan**

Here is simple code block:

```
sql := `SELECT location FROM tb_champ WHERE is_active = true LIMIT 1;`
var location string
row := app.Repo.QueryRow(sql)
fmt.Printf("%T\n %v\n\n", row, row)
err = row.Scan(&location)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(location)
```

Here is output:

```
*pgx.connRow
&{0xc0000b2048 0xc000152240 0xc0001441e0 [] 0 0xc0000a26c0 [] {13797143304121583776 6737745 0x1a8c9c0} SELECT location FROM tb_champ WHERE is_active = true LIMIT 1; [[]] true <nil> <nil>}

expected 0 arguments, got 1
```

My App struct:

```
type App struct {
   Config       *Config
   Logger       *Logger
   Repo         Repository
}
```

...

```
type Repository interface {
   Exec(query string, args ...interface{}) (pgconn.CommandTag, error)
   Query(query string, args ...interface{}) (pgx.Rows, error)
   QueryRow(query string, args ...interface{}) pgx.Row
   Close() error
}
```

PGRepository implementing Repository:

```
type PGRepository struct {
    *pgxpool.Pool
}
```

...
Here is QueryRow implementation:

```
func (pg *PGRepository) QueryRow(query string, args ...interface{}) pgx.Row {
   tx, err := pg.Begin(context.Background())
   if err != nil {
       return nil
   }
   defer tx.Rollback(context.Background())

   res := tx.QueryRow(context.Background(), query, args)
   if err != nil {
       return nil
   }

   err = tx.Commit(context.Background())
   if err != nil {
       return nil
   }

   return res
}
```

Need help! I don't understand which arguments about in error? How to fix this error?

**AFTER @mkopriva COMMENT** (ashamed of my code):

```
res := tx.QueryRow(context.Background(), query, args)
```

changed to

```
res := tx.QueryRow(context.Background(), query, args...)
```

Argument error is gone. But now some problem in `tx.Commit` row appeared: `conn busy`

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but `res := tx.QueryRow(context.Background(), query, args)` is wrong, it should be `res := tx.QueryRow(context.Background(), query, args...)` in the `QueryRow` method of your `*PGRepository` implementation.

Comment: @mkopriva, oh!!! such a shame... thank you